# Mailer issue with SMTP in CakePhp 4

Tags: cakephp, smtp, cakephp-4.x

I am using CakePHP 4.2.8 and trying to send email via smtp, but i am getting time out error and used same email account in other php app (using phpmailer ) and its working fine.
Here is my code.

```php
use Cake\Mailer\Mailer;
use Cake\Mailer\TransportFactory;

public function sendEmail()
{
    TransportFactory::setConfig('Manual', [
        'className' => 'Smtp',
        //'className' => 'Debug',
        'host' => 'mail.abc.com',
        'port' => 465,
        'username' => 'support@abc.com',
        'password' => 'password',
        'tls' => true // Tired with true and false
    ]);

    $mailer = new Mailer('default');
    $mailer->setTransport('Manual');

    try {
        $res = $mailer->setFrom(['support@abc.com' => 'My Site'])
        ->setTo('xyz@gmail.com')
        ->setSubject('About')
        ->deliver('My message');
    pr($res);
    } catch (\Throwable $th) {
        ec($th);
    }
}
```

Getting this error

```php
Cake\Network\Exception\SocketException Object
(
    [_attributes:protected] => Array
        (
        )
    [_messageTemplate:protected] => 
    [_responseHeaders:protected] => 
    [_defaultCode:protected] => 0
    [message:protected] => SMTP timeout.
    [string:Exception:private] => 
    [code:protected] => 0
    [file:protected] => /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/cake/superpad/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Mailer/Transport/SmtpTransport.php
    [line:protected] => 510
```

Please help me what is wrong with my code.  Using same port and other info its working with phpmailer in core php web app.

Thanks

## UPDATE

I found solutions, port should be 587.